# Rounding integer to floating point towards 0

Tags: c++, c

When I do something like the following:

```
long x1 = LONG_MAX;
float x2 = x1;
long x3 = x2;
```

I get the following:

```
x1 = 2147483647
x2 = 2147483648
x3 = -2147483648
```

Is there any way to do the rounding from x1 to x2 towards 0 (or even simply towards negative infinity)?

Comment: Jay posted a correct answer then deleted it...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're interested in the standard IEEE 754 [rounding modes](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Rounding.html)?

The link is to libc; I'm not sure if this ever got standardized as part of the language itself.

I suppose this would work (untested):

```
    #include <math.h>

    int save_round_mode = fegetround();

    fesetround (FE_TOWARDZERO);
    /* do stuff here */
    fesetround (save_round_mode);
```

Comment: These functions are in fact part of the C99 standard, from the header file `<fenv.h>`.  However, be wary of compiler optimizations—you may need to surround your code with a `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on`/`#pragma STD FENV_ACCESS off` block.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [wikipedia for float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) for information on IEEE-754.

If 2147483648 convert to a float, it will be like

```
(1).0000...000 x 2 power 32  NOTICE there are twenty-three '0's after the point
```

and perfectly equals 2147483648.

However, for 2147483647, it is impossible to store 'all information' of the integer number. Thus, it have to be converted to the same float as 2147483648.

Let's see the less float nearest 2147483647, it's

```
(1).1111...111 x 2 power 31  NOTICE there are twenty-three '1's after the point
```

The number is 2147483520, much further than 2147483648 from 2147483647.

So you see why it should have to be 2147483648.

Comment: =,=My English is poor and I haven't got your idea until just now... Maybe, you meant you want to get the answer '2147483520'? Well, the rounding pattern is mentioned for decimal fractional part but not for the integer part. For example, 1.6 rounding towards 0 is 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fix your problem in general, but if you use double instead of float, this works if long is 32 bits.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long x1 = LONG_MAX;
  double x2 = x1;
  long x3 = x2;

  printf("x1 = %d\n", x1);
  printf("x2 = %f\n", x2);
  printf("x3 = %d\n", x3);
}
```